# How embed audio streaming(RTMP) using Phonegap?

Tags: cordova, audio, video, phonegap-build, jwplayer

I want to embed this [audio player](http://directradios.com/gerador3w/test/player.php?width=300&height=30&autoplay=1&controles=1&skin=six&share=0&autoreconect=1&url=rtmp://shflash.directradios.com/furgfm/stream&tipo=1&logo=&posicao=top-right&site=) and this [video player](http://directradios.com/gerador3w/test/player.php?width=400&height=300&autoplay=1&controles=1&skin=six&share=1&autoreconect=1&url=rtmp://shflash.directradios.com/furgtv/stream&tipo=1&logo=&posicao=top-right&site=) (replace furgfm to furgtv) to my app using Phonegap, both are using RTMP.
The audio player is showing like this in my device, but have a lot of bugs(if click to play, the player is hidden, and you have to tap twice to show)

[player](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILc8C.jpg) ,
and the video player doesn't show any image.

I tried a lot of things to make the player looks like "more native", like with jwplayer in my app, or using video.js, but I didn't get success.

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: video player link: http://directradios.com/gerador3w/test/player.php?width=400&height=300&autoplay=1&controles=1&skin=six&share=1&autoreconect=1&url=rtmp://shflash.directradios.com/furgtv/stream&tipo=1&logo=&posicao=top-right&site=

Comment: To your `config.xml`, add this line `<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.7.0" />`. This will remove the need for using the *whitelist* system, which is required since Cordova 5.0.0 (aka *Phonegap Build* `cli-5.1.1`). If this works as you expect, I'll add an answer.